# python property how to somehow overload += on a setter

Tags: python

I have a question regarding the use of decorators.
I am coding a class function that drive a motor stage.
Here is a skeleton:

```
class Stage(object):    
    def get_position(self):
        print("Getting Position")
        return 0

    def set_position_absolute(self, value):
        print("Setting Position Absolute %f"%value)

    def set_position_relative(self, value):
        print("Setting Position Relative %f"%value)

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.get_position()

    @x.setter
    def x(self,value):
        self.set_position_absolute(value)
```

The stage position (let's say x), can be:

- set in an "absolute" way with a value: the new x must be equal to the value (x=value).
- set in an "relative" way with a value: the new x is equal to former_value + value ( x+= value)

What I would like to do, is to use the decorator in such a way that if I use something like:

```
stage.x += 10
```

the setter will use only the method set_position_relative(10), instead of calling both get_position() and set_position_absolute(10) (as it is the case now).

Comment: That doesn't make sense. What if `stage.x` is currently `10`. Shouldn't `stage.x += 10` then use `set_position_absolute(20)`? How *else* would `stage.x += 10` know that now the value is `20`?

Comment: Why do you use properties if you could've used a simple class variable, like `self.x=0` in the constructor and then modify it the way you want.

Comment: But if you actually had a `set_position_relative(10)` method, then you want `stage.x` to support an `__iadd__` method. You should have the `x` property return a special object that implements that method.

Comment: This does not [currently seem possible](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#property) using the `@property`. Maybe define a separate `position` class with the [correct operator overloading](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/operator-overloading-python), in this case `__iadd__(self, other)`

Comment: @kamik423: sure it can be done with `property`. Just return that position class.